# error of install ipython 0.10.0 on Linux red hat 4.4

Tags: python, linux, wxpython, ipython

I am trying to install ipython 0.10.0  on Linux Red Hat 4.4.4-17.

I use instructions on: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html

```
$ tar -xzf ipython.tar.gz
$ cd ipython
$ python setup.py install
```

but, I got:

```
import pkg_resources
    Zope.Interface: yes
           Twisted: Not found (required for parallel computing
                    capabilities)
          Foolscap: Not found (required for parallel computing
                    capabilities)
           OpenSSL: 0.10
            sphinx: Not found (required for building documentation)
          pygments: Not found (required for syntax highlighting
                    documentation)
              nose: Not found (required for running the test suite)
           pexpect: no (required for running standalone doctests)

running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts

changing mode of /home/user/usr/bin/ipengine to 755
changing mode of /home/user/usr/bin/ipcontroller to 755
changing mode of /home/user/usr/bin/ipcluster to 755
changing mode of /home/user/usr/bin/ipython to 755
changing mode of /home/user/usr/bin/ipythonx to 755
changing mode of /home/user/usr/bin/ipython-wx to 755
changing mode of /home/user/usr/bin/pycolor to 755
changing mode of /home/user/usr/bin/irunner to 755
changing mode of /home/user/usr/bin/iptest to 755

running install_data
running install_egg_info

Removing /home/user/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ipython-0.10.1-py2.6.egg-info
Writing /home/user/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ipython-0.10.1-py2.6.egg-info
```

I have used easy_install  to install nose, sphinx, pexpect, pygments.

Why do I still have this error ?

And, another error:

```
$ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/usr/bin/ipython", line 26, in <module>
    import IPython.Shell
ImportError: No module named Shell
```

Thanks

Comment: Red Hat 4 is ancient. Why are you using that?

Comment: it is gcc version, linux version is 2.6.32